# Open file in existing emacs frame (Windows)

Tags: windows, emacs, emacs24

I'm using Emacs 24.3 on Windows 8. I want to be able to right-click a file and select "Edit with Emacs" and have the file open in an existing emacs frame. All steps I have done so far are listed below. Most of it was taken direction from the [Emacs documentation page for Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Installing-Emacs.html).

The following are the registry keys I used to add "Edit with Emacs" to my context menu:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\openwemacs]
@="&Edit with Emacs"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\openwemacs\command]
@="C:\\Portable Software\\emacs-24.3\\bin\\emacsclientw.exe -n \"%1\""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\openwemacs]
@="Edit &with Emacs"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\openwemacs\command]
@="C:\\Portable Software\\emacs-24.3\\bin\\emacsclientw.exe --alternate-editor=\"C:\\Portable Software\\emacs-24.3\\bin\\runemacs.exe\" -n \"%1\""
```

I also set the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` environment variable to `C:\\path\\to\\runemacs.exe`

At the beginning of my `.emacs` I have added the following code per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397323/how-to-avoid-the-message-of-server-start-while-opening-another-emacs-session?rq=1).

```
(require 'server)
(or (server-running-p)
     (server-start))
```

Adding that got rid of the "server already running" error when opening a second file, but it still opens in a new frame.

So what am I missing to get emacs to open new files in the existing frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accidentally figured this out while trying to fix `synctex` with SumatraPDF. It would appear that in addition to the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` environment variable pointing to `runemacs.exe`, you must also create an `EMACS_SERVER_FILE` environment variable that points to the server file (mine was stored in the `.emacs.d\server` directory). Once I did that, files that I tell to Open with Emacs opened in the existing frame rather than creating their own.

Comment: I'm interested in doing this as well. How did you set the environment variables?

Comment: @Calculemus here's a source for how to set environment variables on Windows https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Create `C:\Program Files\runemacs.bat` with the following contents:

```
@echo off

:: Set the path to where the Emacs binaries are
set binpath=C:\Program Files\emacs-26.1-x86_64\bin

:: If no arg is given edit this file
if "%~1"=="" (
  set filename="C:\Program Files\runemacs.bat"
) else (
  set filename="%~1"
)

:: Run Emacsclient
"%binpath%\emacsclientw.exe" --no-wait --alternate-editor="%binpath%\runemacs.exe" %filename%
```

And open all files via `C:\Program Files\runemacs.bat` instead of `C:\Program Files\emacs-26.1-x86_64\bin\runemacs.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that emacsclient is failing to connect with the server and starting a new instance of emacs each time.  You may need to unblock something in any software firewall you have installed.

Comment: Any ideas what I would need to unblock?

Comment: It depends on the firewall software, but most firewalls will block Emacs from creating a listening socket, so you need to add Emacs to a whitelist (or remove it from the blacklist it got put on when it first got blocked).  Some may also block emacsclient from making connections as a client.

Comment: I just created a firewall rule for Windows Firewall to allow connections to runemacs.exe. No change in opening behavior.

Comment: emacs.exe is what you need to allow connections to, runemacs.exe exists only to start emacs.exe without a command prompt window.

Comment: I just changed to rule to allow connections to emacs.exe, but it's still opening new files in new windows.

Comment: I deleted the `.emacs.d\server\server` file and restarted Emacs. Then it suddenly worked!